# Should we always use a hook or is it ok to directly call it from the client?

Tags: apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

In React, we can use the `useMutation` or `useQuery` inside components. But let's say we want to run the query or the mutation inside a helper file (Let's say we extract the part where we format the data and execute the mutation to a helper function away from the component function). In here, we have two options:

- Pass the mutation function obtained from `useMutation` to the helper function
- Call the mutation directly inside the helper function like `apolloClient.mutate`

What is the most recommended way of doing things and what do you recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hooks expose additional component state for the returned data, loading state and error state. This is really just a convenience because it means you don't have to call `useState` yourself. As such, it's perfectly fine to use `client.mutate` if you don't need to keep track of those states. In a sense, it may be *better* since you're not needlessly using memory for variables you won't use anyway.

The same could be said for `useQuery`, which really just uses `client.watchQuery` under the hood and saves you from having to use `useState` and `useEffect`.